# Problem with showing my packets in console with ACE

Tags: c++, packet, ace

for Debug reasons i want to show my outgoing packets in Console.
The packets arrive at the server correctly btw.
But if i want them to show in Console before sending, then it is showing just nothing:

```
    ACE_Message_Block *m_Header;

    ...

    size_t send_len = m_Header->length(); // Size of the Message Block

    char* output = m_Header->rd_ptr();
    printf("Output: %s", output); // Trying to show it in Console
    // Send it
    server.send(m_Header->rd_ptr(), send_len);
```

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the data you send contains 0's - and you'll need to append a newline as well.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < send_len; ++i) {
  if (output[i]<32) {
    printf("\\x%02hhx", (unsigned char) output[i]);
  } else {
    printf("%c", output[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Ah thx, now it is showing me:
\x00\x06\x09\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c
Is it possible to show as Decimal ?

Comment: @Sapd: Change the first printf to e.g. `printf("<%hhi>", output[i]);`